# How to implement twilio Click To Call over VoIP?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I have implemented the Click to Call functionality in my web application.
The flow goes like this

`Customer Req Call -> Twilio Call Customer -> Twilio Call Agent -> Both are connected`.

Are the calls in the above mentioned scenario are made using VoIP?. If not, how to implement the same using twilio Voice SDK and make VoIP Calls instead of using traditional telephony lines.

Twilio documents mentions the twilio supports VoIP on browser, iOS and Android platforms. Does that mean I can make use of twilio voice SDK to make VoIP calls only between browser, iOS and Android devices?

Or I can initiate a call from browser to the actual person number as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The call leg that goes to your customer on the phone will be made over traditional telephone lines.

You can however use [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript) to make VOIP calls from your browser and have Twilio connect that call to the customer on their phone.

Check out [this tutorial on making calls from your browser to phones](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/browser-calls) to understand more.

Comment: Have few questions here.

In twilio page, the pricing for regular call and voip are mentioned as below

https://www.twilio.com/voice/pricing

Local Calls - 0.0130/min
Browser/App Calls -  0.0040/min.

So when we make VoIP call from browser to Customer Phone, the call will be charged at 0.0040/min even though the customer is not using browser or app to receive the call.

Comment: So, in this case you have two call legs, the leg from the browser to Twilio and the leg from Twilio to the customer's phone. The browser to Twilio leg is charged at 0.0040/min and the Twilio to phone leg is charged at 0.0130/min.